# Java subclass does not recognise its generic superclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I need help with a problem I have with generics in Java. I'm writing this Computer algebra system, where the user enters a math expression and the system works with it in different ways (expand it, simplify it etc). It worked fine for expressions containing natural numbers, and I wanted to expand it to work with mathematical sets as well. Instead of +, you would have the intersection operator, etc.

At first, I started recording everything for the sets, but then I realized this was probably not good and started using generics.

Instead of having one parse tree like `MathExpr` and one like `SetExpr`, I thought I could just have a generic `Expression<T>` and build a base class `Number` and a base class `Set`.

To try to clarify, I want a mathematical expression like (2 * a) + (3 + 2) to be an instance of a class `Expression<Number>` and a set expression like (A ∪ B) ∩ C to be an instance of `Expression<Set>`. I can then perform different operations on this, like calculate the depth etc.

The + operation is implemented as one class, the * as one class etc. Both these classes are subclasses of an abstract class called `TwoExpr` which in turn is a subclass of the abstract class `Expr`. This is how I have done it now and everything works fine.

When I wanted to change my code I made my `Expr` class generic. That is `Expr<T>`. I also changed TwoExpr to `TwoExpr<T>` and created a base class `Number`.

The problem is, now I can't seem to instantiate objects of the type `Sum<Number>`.

I get a "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Sum to Expr<Number>`" error. But `Sum` is a subclass of `TwoExpr<Number>`, which in turn is a subclass of `Expr<Number>`. As you may realize, I can't make the class `Sum` generic and call it `Sum<Number>`, because all arithmetic operations don't have analogues for sets.

I have always been able to create objects like

```
Expr zero= new Leaf(0);
Variable a = new Variable("a");
Expr aPlusZero = new Sum(a, zero);
```

When I changed to generics, the same code looks like this:

```
Expr<Number> zero= new Leaf<Number>(new Number(0)); //works fine
Variable<Number> a = new Variable<Number>("a");     //works fine
Expr<Number> APlusZero=new Sum(a,zero); //gives a "Type mismatch:
//cannot convert from Sum to Expr<Number>" error
```

How come it doesn't recognize that `Sum(a,zero)` is a subclass of `Expr<Number>`, when it says in the declaration of Sum

```
public class Sum extends TwoExpr<Number> {

    public Sum(Expr<Number> a, Expr<Number> b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
...
}
```

and in the declaration of TwoExpr

```
public abstract class TwoExpr<T> extends Expr<T> {

    protected Expr<T> a;
    protected Expr<T> b;

    public TwoExpr(Expr<T> a, Expr<T> b) {
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
    ...
}
```

I know that Lizkows substitution principle doesn’t apply for generic arguments. But Number isn’t a subclass of anything (except Object) and don't have any subclasses.
I hope I've been fairly clear about what I'm trying to do and what problem I have. Does anybody have any idea how to solve it? Please tell me if anything was unclear in the above or if you want more code.

Thanks in advance.

Mattias

Comment: Could it be that the compiler mixes your Number type with `java.lang.Number`?

Comment: Your code given here looks fine, I dare to say that the problem is not in the part you've shown here.

Comment: Agreed, a missing "import ...Number" may be the culprit.

Comment: Well, he's definitely not using java.lang.Number if new Number(0) works. lang.Number is abstract. That wouldn't work with it.

Comment: No, Number is not java.lang.number and Set is not Collections.Set. Those Are both classes I have created. Number is just a wrapper for int and Set is just a wrapper for String.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in the classes you did not show, I tried the following and it works:

```
Expr<Number> zero= new Expr<Number>();
Expr<Number> a= new Expr<Number>(); 
Expr<Number> APlusZero=new Sum(a,zero);
```

Might it be that Variable is not an Expr?

UPDATE:

I played a little creating Variable and Leaf as I imagine them and it all works:

```
public class Number {

    public Number(int i){}
}


public class Variable<T> extends Expr<T> {

    public Variable(String s){}
}


public class Leaf<T> extends Expr<T> {

    public Leaf(T t) {
        super();
    }
}


public class Expr<T> {

}


public class TwoExpr<T> extends Expr<T> {

    public TwoExpr(Expr<T> a, Expr<T> b) {
    }
}


public class Sum extends TwoExpr<Number> {

    public Sum(Expr<Number> a, Expr<Number> b) {
        super(a, b);
    }
}


public class AllTogether {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Expr<Number> zero= new Leaf<Number>(new Number(0));
        Variable<Number> a = new Variable<Number>("a");
        Expr<Number> APlusZero=new Sum(a,zero);
    }
}
```

If you take the extends Expr from Variable it does give the error you experience, might it be this the cause?

Comment: the declaration of Variable is public class Variable<T> extends Atomic<T> and the declaration of Atomic is public abstract class Atomic<T> extends Expr<T> so that shouldnt be it, those sort of things worked out perfectly before I added generics so that shouldnt be it

Comment: I wanted to create a similar example to show that there is no error here, but didn't had the time yet - thanks!

Comment: @Mattias, does the example given here compile for you? If not, which compiler are you using? (Maybe we are chasing a compiler bug here.)

Comment: Yes, it did compile. However, there are a couple of differences in your code and mine, for example, Expr and TwoExpr are abstract. When I introduced generics, I also moved the different classes to different packages, could that be it, that it doesn't recognize the classes anymore because they are not in the same package? I use eclipse helios.

Comment: I would advice you to update your question and put all the involved classes (declaration and constructors is enough) so we can try it. Otherwise we are inventing things that actually work but differ from your code

Comment: Yes, I will do that. I didn't want to post all classes because I thought it was confusing but I think youre right. I will post all relevant classes and packages.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to debug it:

```
Object = new Sum(a,zero);
System.out.println(o.getClass().getGenericSuperclass());
```

Furthermore maybe  is a better solution for your system.

Comment: But I cant even run the program. The Line `Object=new Sum(a,zero);` gives the error message "The constructor Sum(Variable<Number>, Expr<Number>) is undefined". But the constructor of Sum is `public Sum(Expr<Number> a, Expr<Number> b) {`
  `super(a, b);`
 `}`

Comment: If Variable<T> extends Expr<T>, shouldnt Variable<Number> extend Expr<Number>?

Answer (score 0):

`Sum` does not import `Types.Number`. So it's not `Expr<Types.Number>` but `Expr<java.lang.Number>`. I would assume this would give a compilation error not only on the assignment but also on the construction of `new Sum(vA, zero)`, but maybe the compiler sees the other error first.

Comment: Well, what do you know... I didn't see that. It should of course be Types.Number. But Variable doesn't import Number either and it works for that one.

Comment: I thought that because Sum was in the package Types.Number.Two it would automatically import all classes in Number, but I have a feeling Im getting packages in java wrong.

Comment: Packages are arranged into trees merely as a convenience. Package "com.example.foo" is not related to "com.example" in any semantic meaningful way.